# ubuntu создать zip

Tags: ubuntu, zip

хочу создать zip архив на серверe
знаю как создать, только мне нужно, чтоб создать только zip на конкретную, а не вложенную

сейчас создает zip с вложением как /var/www/html/site/files, а мне нужно, чтоб создал только /files

Comment: покажите команду, которую вы выполняете, и из какой папки исполняете команду.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Устанавливаем

```
$ sudo apt install zip unzip
```

Переходим в нужную папку

```
$ cd /var/www/html/site/
```

Архивируем нужную папку, с нужным названием.

```
$ zip -r files.zip files
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]